# Адаптация скрипта под PHP 5.3

Tags: php, dle

Имеется следующий скрипт:

```
<?php
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM dle_users");
$row = $db->get_row($result);
?>
<?php 
foreach($result as $key => $row) {
    $xfields = $row['xfields'];
    $fields = explode('|',$xfields);
    if(!empty($fields[1]) && !empty($fields[4])) {
        echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$fields[1].'</td>
                <td>'.$fields[4].'</td>
            </tr>
            ';
    }
}
?>
```

Данный скрипт прекрасно отрабатывает на локалке PHP 5.6
Но почему то при переносе на хостинг где стоит PHP 5.3 Скрипт попросту не работает, пустота.

Как решить вопрос с совместимостью? Всем спасибо.

Comment: БД настроена правильно в var_dump содержится массив

Comment: проверьте так:  $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM dle_users");
$row = $db->get_row($result); printr($row);   // должен вывести массив.

Comment: Что содержит в себе ` $result`?

Comment: При данном запросе $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM dle_users"); $row = $db->get_row($result); printr($row); выводится ошибка Fatal error: Call to undefined function printr() in /var/www/u01211/public_html/site.ru/company.php on line 2

Comment: var_dump($result) содержит object(mysqli_result)#6 (5)

Comment: print_r  - извини опечатался)

Comment: С помощью чего вы  с базой работаете? ezSQL?

Comment: Print_r вывел массив. С базой работаю через dle api =))) Основа в принципе такая же как и у ezsql

Comment: А можно как нибудь по другому решить вопрос, без сильного изменения конструкции кода? Интересно почему он на локалке работал))

Comment: Можете посмотреть пример в пункте **Выбор множества строк** (ezSQL) тут http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=769

Comment: "Метод `get_row` используется для извлечения строки из базы данных " предположу что на локалке у вас был одни пользователь  и соответственно одна строка, а сейчас строк больше(

Comment: Нет, пользователь на хостинге тоже один)

Comment: @Дима,  код всё-равно переделывать под х юзеров, поэтому используй $db->get_results

Comment: Можете показать конструкцию кода, что бы я дальше переделывал скрипт

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM dle_users");
$row = $db->get_row($result);
?>
<?php 
foreach($row as $key => $value) {
    $xfields = $value['xfields'];
    $fields = explode('|',$xfields);
    if(!empty($fields[1]) && !empty($fields[4])) {
        echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$fields[1].'</td>
                <td>'.$fields[4].'</td>
            </tr>
            ';
    }
}
?>
```

Много строчный вариант:

```
 $results = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM dle_users");

foreach ( $results as $user ) {
    $xfields = $user->xfields;
    $fields = explode('|',$xfields);
    if(!empty($fields[1]) && !empty($fields[4])) {
        echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$fields[1].'</td>
                <td>'.$fields[4].'</td>
            </tr>
            ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Все равно NULL ))

Comment: @Дима, `var_dump($results);` что выдает после запроса? :)

Comment: @Дима  путем простого `echo`  и `print_r` (для массивов)  найди какая переменная NULL

Comment: Дело в том, что сам массив NULL выдает

Comment: `$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM dle_users"); $row = $db->get_row($result); print_r($row); ` покажи что выводит, так

Comment: Array ( [email] => admin@site.com [password] => 5a288a395cf9951512186e275e1b8705 [name] => admin [user_id] => 1 [news_num] => 23 [comm_num] => 3 [user_group] => 1 [lastdate] => 1441361272 [reg_date] => 1441053104 [banned] => [allow_mail] => 1 [info] => [signature] => [foto] => [fullname] => [land] => [favorites] => [pm_all] => 0 [pm_unread] => 0 [time_limit] => [xfields] => company_name|ООО ||specify|репараты||country|Москва [allowed_ip] => [hash] => [logged_ip] => 178.??.???.186 [restricted] => 0 [restricted_days] => 0 [restricted_date] => [timezone] => )

Comment: @Дима  обновил ответ, возможно была путаница в переменных